# Predicate formula to propositional formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have: 
$$\begin{align}
\exists x \forall y P(x,y) \\
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
M=\{a,b\} \\
\end{align}$$
I need to convert this formula to propositional logic. I know that if `M` is finite then you can eliminate quantifier, but what can I do when there is **two quantifiers**? Any hints, help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to eliminate quantifiers *step by step*:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exists x\forall yP(x,y) &\iff \exists x (P(x,a)\land P(x,b))\\
&\iff \left(P(a,a)\land P(a,b)\right)\lor \left(P(b,a)\land P(b,b)\right).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: is order of eliminating quantifiers important?

Comment: @user2965303 It is not important.

Comment: If you eliminate quantifiers by different order you may get formula whose form is difficult to the form of that. But these two are logically equivalent.